# Maze solver, diagonal moves only

Tags: java, recursion, maze

I was given some code that already contained everything to build a maze. I was to write the makeMove method to solve the maze, which I have completed here:

```
int MAX_ROWS = endRow + 1;
int MAX_COLS = endCol + 1;
boolean[][]visited = new boolean[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
protected void makeMove( int row, int col )
{
    boolean found = false;
    if (row < 0 || row >= MAX_ROWS  || col < 0 || col >= MAX_COLS  || visited[row][col] || maze[row][col] == 1)
        return;

    visited[row][col] = true;
    found = row == endRow && col == endCol;

    if (!found) {
        makeMove(row, col - 1);
        makeMove(row, col + 1);
        makeMove(row - 1, col);
        makeMove(row + 1, col);
    }
  System.out.print("\n[" + row + "," + col + "] ");    // display location
}//end makeMove
```

}

with this it is assumed that the start is at top left and end is at bottom right, this code works like it should.

however, now I need to modify it so that it only allows for diagonal moves....

and I'm at a stand still, drawing a blank on how to accomplish this

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: Not much of a maze, since you seem to be allowing the code to go through walls.

Comment: @MarcB I think that's what the `maze[row][col] == 1` is for.

Comment: @MarB a '1' represents a wall, if it hits a wall it backtracks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
makeMove(row - 1, col - 1);
makeMove(row - 1, col + 1);
makeMove(row + 1, col - 1);
makeMove(row + 1, col + 1);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if its kind of a trick question and i'm just over thinking how it is done, but another task is to modify any methods need to use 1-d array for maze, and visited instead of 2-D. would I only need columns, or would i need to add the rows to columns somehow? Thanks for all your help

Comment: You should ask other questions as new questions, but I can help you out. You can map a 2D array to a 1D array quite easily. Declare the array as `boolean[] visited = new boolean[MAX_ROWS * MAX_COLS]` and then use `visited[MAX_COLS * row + col]` to access an element at a particular row and column. You can think of it as taking the 2D array and joining the rows together to form a long 1D array.

Comment: I asked a new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126813/changing-2-d-maze-solver-to-be-used-with-1-d

Comment: how would I change maze[][]?